# Using the Bockstein to show that $\mathbb{R}P^3/\mathbb{R}P^1$ and $\Sigma \mathbb{R}P^2$ are not homotopy equivalent.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

The previous exercise asked to show that the cohomology rings $H^*(\Sigma \mathbb{R}P^2; \mathbb{Z}/2)$ and $H^*(\mathbb{R}P^3/\mathbb{R}P^1; \mathbb{Z}/2)$ are isomorphic, so we should probably take the Bockstein associated to

$$\mathbb{Z}/2 \to \mathbb{Z}/4 \to \mathbb{Z}/2$$

The cohomology groups are $\mathbb{Z}/2, 0, \mathbb{Z}/2, \mathbb{Z}/2, 0, 0, ...$. As a homotopy equivalence between spaces induces an isomorphism on cohomology groups it suffices to show that the only non-trivial Bockstein from second to third cohomology has a different action.

We can use the universal coefficients theorem to calculate $H^2(\Sigma \mathbb{R}P^2; \mathbb{Z}/4) \cong H^1(\mathbb{R}P^2; \mathbb{Z}/4) \cong \mathbb{Z}/2$, $H^2(\mathbb{R}P^3/\mathbb{R}P^1; \mathbb{Z}/4) \cong 0$, $H^3(\Sigma \mathbb{R}P^2; \mathbb{Z}/4) \cong H^2(\mathbb{R}P^2; \mathbb{Z}/4) \cong (\mathbb{Z}/4)/2 \cong \mathbb{Z}/2$ and $H^3(\mathbb{R}P^3/\mathbb{R}P^1; \mathbb{Z}/4) \cong \mathbb{Z}/4$. As the second homology with $\mathbb{Z}/4$ coefficients differ, we can already conclude that the spaces are not homotopy equivalent.

So we finally detect a difference. The long exact sequence associated to $\Sigma \mathbb{R}P^2$ is

$$\mathbb{Z}/2 \to \mathbb{Z}/2 \to \mathbb{Z}/2 \xrightarrow{\beta} \mathbb{Z}/2 \to \mathbb{Z}/2 $$

and the one associated to $\mathbb{R}P^3/\mathbb{R}P^1$ is

$$\mathbb{Z}/2 \to 0 \to \mathbb{Z}/2 \xrightarrow{\beta} \mathbb{Z}/2 \to \mathbb{Z}/4$$

So the second $\beta$ must be the identity, while the first one could possibly be zero.

Source:
[image]

Comment: I believe $H^1(\mathbb{RP}^2; \mathbb{Z}_4) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$, not $0$.

Comment: Can you provide more context, like maybe tell us if this is from a book (and which book it's from) or if it's been assigned by a professor? It seems like a very odd exercise, because it order to argue with a Bockstein exact sequence it seems like you'll either have to compute cohomology with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}/4$ (like in your attempt) or $\mathbb{Z}$ (using the sequence $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/2$), and the results of these computations *already* show these spaces are not homotopy-equivalent.

Comment: @William It's an exercise assigned by a professor. I'll put a picture of the exact exercise in the post.

Comment: What do you know about the Bockstein so far? Are there any formal properties that you can use?

Comment: $H^2(\mathbb{RP}^3/\mathbb{RP}^1; \mathbb Z/4)$ is also $\mathbb{Z}/2$ instead of $0$, look at the "coefficients in an abelian group" heading here: https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Cohomology_of_real_projective_space#Cohomology_groups_in_piecewise_form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is an exercise for a course, I will try to give hints rather than a complete answer. I don't know what you've covered in your course so far, so hopefully you're able to fill in the gaps with your available material (the proofs I have in mind use relatively basic properties). In this answer all cohomology groups are assumed to have $\mathbb{Z}/2$ coefficients.

The Bockstein is a *stable* cohomology operation, meaning that if $\sigma \colon \tilde{H}^*(X) \to \tilde{H}^{*+1}(\Sigma X)$ is the suspension isomorphism then we have the following commutative diagram: 
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
H^n(X) @>{\beta}>> H^{n+1}(X)\\
@V{\sigma}VV @V{\sigma}VV\\
H^{n+1}(\Sigma X) @>{\beta}>> H^{n+2}(\Sigma X)
\end{CD}

i.e. $\beta\circ \sigma = \sigma \circ \beta$. Use stability to compute $\beta \colon H^2(\Sigma \mathbb{RP}^2) \to H^3(\Sigma \mathbb{RP}^2)$.

It is also *natural*, in particular the quotient map $q\colon \mathbb{RP}^3 \to \mathbb{RP}^3/\mathbb{RP}^1$ gives a commutative diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
H^2(\mathbb{RP}^3/\mathbb{RP}^1) @>{\beta}>> H^3(\mathbb{RP}^3/\mathbb{RP}^1)\\
@V{q^*}VV @V{q^*}VV\\
H^2(\mathbb{RP}^3) @>{\beta}>> H^3(\mathbb{RP}^3)
\end{CD}

Note that the vertical maps are isomorphisms by the long exact sequence of the pair. Use this diagram to help compute $\beta \colon H^2(\mathbb{RP}^3/\mathbb{RP}^1) \to H^3(\mathbb{RP}^3/\mathbb{RP}^1)$.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. The commutative diagrams show that the bockstein of $\Sigma \mathbb{R}P^2$ and $\mathbb{R}P^3/\mathbb{R}P^1$ are essentially the same as those of $\mathbb{R}P^2$ and $\mathbb{R}P^3$. Is there some easy way to calculate the bockstein between projective spaces?

Comment: For $\beta\colon H^2(\mathbb{RP}^3) \to H^3(\mathbb{RP}^3)$ use the fact that the domain is generated by $w^2$ and that $\beta$ is a derivation. For $\beta \colon H^1(\mathbb{RP}^2) \to H^2(\mathbb{RP}^2)$ you can compute it directly from the Bockstein exact sequence, using the fact that $H^1(\mathbb{RP}^2;\mathbb{Z}/4) \cong \mathbb{Z}/2$; you can also use the fact that $\beta = Sq^1$ and use the Wu formula; (there may be another more elementary way of computing it that I don't know of).

Comment: I had one lecture on the bockstein, so I don't know what a deriviation and the Wu formula are yet, but I'll keep it in mind for later in the course.

Comment: In this particular case by a "derivation" on a graded ring $R$ I mean an additive function $d\colon R^* \to R^{*+1}$ such that if $a\in R^p$ and $b \in R^q$ then $d(a\cdot b) = d(a)\cdot b + (-1)^p a\cdot d(b)$. Hopefully you've seen a similar formula for the Bockstein. (The Wu formula is a bit more advanced.)

Comment: @PeldePinda I don't know why your edit suggestion was rejected by the community, of course I meant to put $\Sigma X$ there, thanks!